# What's a word to describe "not okay with but not complaining"

Tags: single-word-requests

What word would you use to describe "not being comfortable with something or someone, yet not complaining"?

A perfect example is when you don't enjoy your partner's meal but you are not complaining. A word like acquiesce is close in meaning, but I want the best word.

Comment: *uncomfortable*?

Comment: Not uncomfortable

Comment: You bear it (or them)?

Comment: How would you use the term in a sentence?

Comment: A perfect example is when you don't enjoy your partner's meal but you are not complaining. Words like acquiesce is nearest in meaning. But i wanted a perfect word.

Answer (score 4):

Then you **tolerate** it. The word *tolerance*, from [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tolerance):

> 1. willingness to accept feelings, habits, or beliefs that are different from your own;
> 2. the ability to accept, experience, or survive something harmful or unpleasant.

Answer (score 4):

***Resigned to***, from [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/resign-yourself-to-sth)

> To make yourself accept something you do not like because you cannot
>   change it

Example (made up):

> He resigned himself to the awful lines at airport security over the Memorial Day weekend, because it was the last opportunity he would have to visit his parents before starting his new job.

Answer (score 0):

While **tolerate** (per Matsmath) is a perfectly good answer, you might also consider more extreme examples, such as **long-suffering**.

Comment: Acquiesce would be cool. But it doesn't bring out the "not comfortable" part.

Answer (score 0):

There's a question of degree. Is it a little uncomfortable or a lot uncomfortable?

How about **loathe**?

: to dislike greatly; detest
[Webster's]

*Although I am loathe to sit next to the stinky kid, I can always just breathe through my mouth.*

Comment: I think *loathe* does not express the term "not complaining". Your example sentence make it look like to do so, but it is tricky since the second part expresses "not complaining" which has nothing to do with the first part.

Comment: Acquiesce would be cool. But it doesn't bring out the "not comfortable" part.

Answer (score 0):

I would use "disquiet" as it adds nothing.  It is an internal feeling one has when not comfortable with something.

> I felt disquiet when he did not answer.

Answer (score 0):

To *begrudgingly* accept something, perhaps.

**Begrudge** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/begrudge)

> 2. *(with object)* Give reluctantly or resentfully
>    *(adverb)* begrudgingly
>
> *"So I begrudgingly agreed that we would cook something."*
> *"And I begrudgingly have to admit they probably deserved to win."*

Comment: See how I have added extra information like definition, example, dictionary link? Next time you should do it. :)

Comment: the trouble with *begrudge* is that it does imply a good bit of complaining or grumbling, at least to me. It wouldn't work for the partner's meal example, either.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use **Passivity**.

[vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/passivity)

> **Passivity ** is allowing others to do things to you without complaining or pushing back.

Answer (score -1):

The answer I would give disapproval.
Merriam Webster defines it as

> Lack of approval : the belief that someone or something is bad or wrong

Comment: Hi Noah, welcome to ELU! I think your answer is a fair contribution, and congrats for demonstrating research effort (which is greatly prized on this site!). As a suggestion, it could be improved on two scores. Firstly, the way the question is framed suggests that a verb (e.g. disapprove) or adjective (e.g. disapproving) is being asked for. Secondly, the OP asks for a word that captures both "not okay" and "**not complaining**", and I'm not sure that disapproval meets the second requirement unless it's *tacit*.